# How to keep asp.net inputbox from minimizing?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

When the user clicks a button, an inputbox is supposed to pop up asking for some details. This all works, except the inputbox shows up minimized or not in focus.

```
    var = InputBox("enter something")
    ListBox1.Items.Add(var)
```

I've looked for answers, but I haven't found any... So, any ideas on how I could make an inputbox show up in focus?

Comment: What's an `InputBox`?

Comment: Yes, the code above works, but the inputbox shows up out of focus...

Comment: @user2548215: Does this code "work" when it's run on a server and not on your local machine acting as the server?

Comment: The server is not running on the machine I am viewing the page from, and it does "work"

Comment: Can you post a screenshot? I want to see how a native input dialog can show up on a webpage...

Comment: @David: an `InputBox` is (I would have thought) a box used by the Windows programming side of .NET to allow the user to enter information in a string form.  I've not heard of this in the web side of .NET though.

Comment: Perhaps it would be helpful to us if you presented more of your code.

Comment: @user2548215: As you can imagine, you're doing something (or at least attempting to do something) that's *very* non-standard in ASP.NET.  You're asking us how to make that work, but as far as we can tell what you're doing *isn't supposed to work* in ASP.NET at all.  So, we're going to need some more information here.  Maybe a working example?  Do you have a live example you can link to?

Comment: You should be aware that the inputbox is shown on the web server, not your user's machine. And the web app thread will be blocked until someone dismiss the dialog. If you want input from the user, use the javascript [prompt command](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_prompt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can't see most of the code we probably need to see in order to answer your question properly, but have you tried using jQuery's focus method? If your inputbox (or possibly an ASP.NET textbox control? Who knows?) has the class 'myInputBoxClass', then you can focus client-side like so:

```
function focusBox(){
   $('.myInputBoxClass').focus();
};
```